# Microsoft Graph get calendar entries happening today (reaching over timeframe)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm currently struggeling with the `Microsoft Graph REST-API`.

What I'm trying to do is list todays events (happening between midnight and midnight). From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#filter), the filter function is very limited.

My current statement looks like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$top=100&$select=*&$filter=start/DateTime ge '2017-10-31T00:00:00' AND end/DateTime le '2017-11-1T00:00:00'&$orderby=start/DateTime ASC`

The interesting part is here `$filter=start/DateTime ge '2017-10-31T00:00:00' AND end/DateTime le '2017-11-1T00:00:00'` using the `start` and the `end` and checking if `start >= TODAY AND end <= TODAY+1`. That's all working great for dates that are shorter as 1 day.

My problem is now how to get events that last longer than one day e.g. `start = YESTERDAY` and `end = NEXT WEEK`. Which means the start date is before today and the end day is as well not included in this range.

How to get this events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should be using Calendar View for your scenario:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview

Comment: Looks like the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

The link that Yogesh referenced seems to be removed and not found. Here is the link that I used which shows how to use the calendar view. Hopefully this helps -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http